# User authentication and roles in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, user-management

Can anybody suggest me a good tutorial for handling user authentication and roles using AngularJS.

I just want to lock down certain areas of the site to certain users etc just like privileges.

I have googled but didn't find any tutorial speaks about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look at the angular-app project (more particularly its security module) : https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/tree/master/client/src/common/security (which internally uses [angular-http-auth](https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth) module)

This module handles the authentication and securing of routes based on a two-level access : loggedin user and administrator. You can easily update code to handle more roles...